# how do I populate a document mongoose or save refs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a questions collection and I have a store model. I want the questions field in the Store model to be to be the array of object ids from the questions collection. so I could use populate later. when I do app.get in the future it should show me a doc with the store info and all the questions.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var storeSchema = Schema({
    name : {type : String},
    industry : {type : String},
    questions :[{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Questions" }]
})

var questionsSchema = Schema({
    question : {type :String}
})

var store = mongoose.model("Store", storeSchema);
var questions = mongoose.model("Questions", questionsSchema)

// questions.create({question: "question2"}, function(err,q){
//     console.log("create: " , q)
// })
//something like this
questions.find({}, function(err, doc){
    store.create({name : "store 1", industry : "industry 1" , questions : /*get the _ids from the question collection*/ {$push : doc.question}})
})


> db.questions.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("574534a289763c004643fa08"),
        "question" : "question1",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("574534acc90f3f2c0c3d529b"),
        "question" : "question2",
        "__v" : 0
}
>
```

Comment: @jack_blank did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We may populate a single document, multiple documents, plain object, multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query.

```
    var question = new Questions();
    question.save(function(err) {
        var store = new Store({
            name:'sample',
            industry:'tech',
            questions: [question._id],
        });
        store.save(function(err){
         //do whatever you would like, post creation of store.
        });
    });

   Store.find(...).exec(function(err, stores) {
     Questions.populate(stores, function(err, storesPostPopulate) {
      // Now you have Stores populated with all the questions.
     })
   });
```

Since questions field in question schema is an array, you can always push another question id to it.

[See mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

[See mongoose Model populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)

Comment: you cant just do that. you have to set `questions` to something. The Doc calls "saving the ref" so that is my problem. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: how do you add questions without saving a new store and still be able to populate it?  all I see is when you save a question you save a store. I don't want to do that. still don't get it.

Comment: and populate expects a string. `TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof "function"`